# Data analysis with pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot-table, data-analysis, pandas-groupby

The following df is a summary of my hole dataset just to illustrate my problem.
The df shows the job application of each `id` and i want to know which combination of sector is more likely for an individual to apply?

```
df
id    education   area_job_application
 1      Collage           Construction 
 1      Collage                  Sales
 1      Collage         Administration
 2   University                Finance
 2   University                  Sales
 3      Collage                Finance
 3      Collage                  Sales
 4   University         Administration   
 4   University                  Sales
 4   University           Data analyst
 5   University         Administration
 5   University                  Sales
```

answer

```
              Construction    Sales    Administration   Finance   Data analyst
Contruction              1        1                 1         0             0
Sales                    1        5                 3         1             1           
Administration           1        3                 3         0             1
Finance                  0        2                 0         2             0
Data analyst             0        1                 1         0             1
```

This answer shows that administration and sales are the sector that more chances have to receive a postulation by the same id (this is the answer which i am looking). But i am also interesting for other combinations, i think that a mapheat will be very informative to illustrate this data.

Sector combination from the same sector are irrelevant (maybe in the diagonal from the answer matrix should be a 0, doesnt matter the value, i wont anaylse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) or `groupby` with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) first and then [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by transpose `DataFrame` and last add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for custom order of index and columns:

```
#dynamic create order by unique values of column
L = df['area_job_application'].unique()

#df = pd.crosstab(df.id, df.area_job_application)
df = df.groupby(['id', 'area_job_application']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
df = df.T.dot(df).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reindex(columns=L, index=L)
print (df)
                Construction  Sales  Administration  Finance  Data analyst
Construction               1      1               1        0             0
Sales                      1      5               3        2             1
Administration             1      3               3        0             1
Finance                    0      2               0        2             0
Data analyst               0      1               1        0             1
```

Comment: Jez, question if in my real dataset i have many different 'area_job_application', there is other way to map 'L' and pass it to the final answer?

Comment: @LucasDresl - sure, give me a sec.

Comment: give me back the following error `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`

Comment: If use `L = df['area_job_application'].unique().tolist()` same problem?

Comment: my bad, i was doing something wrong, now i try again

Comment: by the way, u know to pass to the diagonal of the matrix a zero?

Comment: Use `np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 0)`

Comment: Btw, in my previous answer I add some timings, if you are interested you can check it.